# Хранение переменных в PHP

Tags: cookie, php, переменные

Здравствуйте. Опыт веб-программирования совсем небольшой. Пишу (пописываю) на yii (ну или учусь - как угодно). Встал вопрос: как сохранить переменную, которая понадобится мне в "будущем", где-то в другом месте кода. Проблема в том, что код выполняется лишь единожды. Для меня это непривычно после С++, где программа работает "постоянно". Скрипт же выполняется 1 раз и "уходит" пользователю. А мне нужно получить ее при следующем выполнении. Так неужели, куки и БД - это все?

Приведу пример (чисто гипотетический):

Выполяется код. Есть переменная $variable - пусть из введенной формы. В обработчике я ее знаю. Но мне она сейчас не нужна, а понадобится позже. Что ее в куки записывать?

Comment: >Так неужели, куки и БД - это все?

Куки, БД, сессии, файлы. Что я забыл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Сессии](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.sessions.php) вам в помощь.

Comment: @kingNothing, то что нужно) первая ссылка из гугла шласит: "Сессии и cookies предназначены для хранения сведений о пользователях при переходах между несколькими страницами."

Comment: Чисто для информации - значение сессий парситься из файлов, т.е. это принципиально ничем не отличается от кук, БД или кастомного файла.

#####<troll>советую сменить язык программировния ^_^</troll>

Comment: @AlexWindHope, на какой же?)

Answer (score 1):

Что значит "после С++, где программа работает "постоянно""? В си точно также код выполняется, программа завершается. Другое дело скажем когда ты создаешь форму в билдере и запускаешь, она типа открыта и всегда запущена, но на нижнем уровне, на сколько я знаю, это просто зацикливание.

Хранить переменные можешь в куки, сессиях, в базе данных.